# Using \leftskip as xleftmargin

Tags: listings

I am typesetting text with varying leftskip (some sections of the text are indented to the right).

For some reason, listings does not take leftskip into account by default. However it has a xleftmargin property that is interesting. It works adequately when given an explicit value, eg. 2cm.

However, I cannot seem to set it to be equal to \leftskip. I tried different variations, including

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\setlength{\leftskip}{5cm}

\begin{document}

totototo

\begin{lstlisting}[xleftmargin={\the\leftskip}]
def example_function():
    print("Hello, world!")
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

But to no avail. What should I say ? In the MWE I could just use `5cm`, but in reality, \leftskip will not always be the same.

Comment: well as you found out listings sets \leftskip to 0pt at the begin so using it in the key doesn't work. You could copy the value into another length and use that. Or patch the PreInit hook and remove the setting: `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\lsthk@PreInit{\leftskip\z@}{}{}{\fail}
\makeatother`

Comment: Thanks so much. No, I had not found out that the reason for that behaviour was listings' own tinkering with leftskip. I could have spun around the problem for days !

Comment: Listings use `\@totalleftmargin`, to which they add `\leftmargin` at each level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocate a new length that is set to `\leftskip` before `lstlisting` does its working; then we can use it as value for `xleftmargin`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newlength{\keepleftskip}

\AtBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\setlength{\keepleftskip}{\leftskip}}
\lstset{xleftmargin=\keepleftskip}

\begin{document}

\noindent
totototo

\begin{lstlisting}
def example_function():
    print("Hello, world!")
\end{lstlisting}

\setlength{\leftskip}{5cm}

\noindent
totototo

\begin{lstlisting}
def example_function():
    print("Hello, world!")
\end{lstlisting}

\setlength{\leftskip}{1cm}

\noindent
totototo

\begin{lstlisting}
def example_function():
    print("Hello, world!")
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Ulrike Fischer pointed out in her comment, `\leftskip` is reset by `\begin{lstlisting}`.

The closest I could get is creating a second length register with the same value and using that one. This would mean that you have to update that register each time you change `\leftskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\newlength{\leftskiphack}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\leftskip}{5cm}
\setlength{\leftskiphack}{\leftskip}

totototo

\begin{lstlisting}[xleftmargin=\the\leftskiphack]
def example_function():
    print("Hello, world!")
\end{lstlisting}

\setlength{\leftskip}{8cm}
\setlength{\leftskiphack}{\leftskip}

totototo

\begin{lstlisting}[xleftmargin=\the\leftskiphack]
def example_function():
    print("Hello, world!")
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```